# SSRS Report translation problems

Tags: reporting-services, translation, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to translate an SSRS report. Using this example [link](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/09/localization-of-your-ssrs-reports.html). The general report is working perfectly(Inside the blue square in the picture below). But i have an issues with finding have to translate the red squares in the picture below. Is it not possible to translate that part(The text in the red square). 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately u can't translate parameters prompt and the 'view report' part as well. Those are not the part of the reports so we can't translate them.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
You can do this, even if the user uses another language.

The secret is passing a parameter for the desired language to the ssrs page. 
Then, you can create a http-module, that gets the language from the URL/referrer (note: HTTP misspells referrer as referer)

Example code:

https://github.com/ststeiger/SSRS-Localizer/blob/master/libRequestLanguageChanger/RequestLanguageChanger.cs

(this code also sets the P3P-header, as this is necessary for the SSRS-cookies in IE if the page is iframed from a page on a different domain)

This sets SSRS into the correct localization mode if the browser language does not correspond to the user language.

If you want, you can, in addition to that, change ReportViewer, usually located in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS<whatever>\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx
```

and translate the report's paramters's labels using JavaScript.

**Note:** 
if you only change the culture in ReportViewer.aspx in method

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
```

then the datepickers won't work. 
Therefore, you need to run it as http-module (and if it loads resources, such as jquery-ui, you need to get the language from the refer[r]er).

Here an example ReportViewer.aspx, where language is passed in url-parameter in_sprache, with parameter labels set in the format `Text_DE / Text_FR / Text_IT / Text_EN` (/ is not necessarely the best separation character, use a character that you don't need)

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="RS" Namespace="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer" Assembly="ReportingServicesWebServer" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportViewerPage" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<asp:literal runat="server" id="docType"></asp:literal>
<html>
<!-- Here InitializeCulture -->
 <head id="headID" runat="server">
  <asp:literal runat="server" id="httpEquiv"></asp:literal>
  <title><%= GetPageTitle() %></title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

html 
{
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFA500;
    scrollbar-base-color: black;
    scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #aaaaaa;
    scrollbar-track-color: black;
    scrollbar-face-color: #3d3d3d;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: gray;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: silver;
    scrollbar-3d-light-color: black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 13px; height: 13px}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover{height: 18px}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
    height: 15px;
    width: 13px;
    display: block;
    background: #101211;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/horizontal-decrement-arrow.png);
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAIAAABLMMCEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAIhJREFUeNpiFBASZIABXj5WHQPB44deMUH4TEyMviGyU5dYXrnwHshlAWIDU6HsUk15JZ4F025//vQbJKpnJNQ8wYidnRnIuX3jE0Qr88cPDHu3PRMQYldU4X1498uVCx9AohycnF+//Dmy7+Wpo288A2TOnXz7/ftfRmQ3AIG6Nv/Nqx8BAgwAwakucAZmLk0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    background-position: 4px 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/horizontal-increment-arrow.png);
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAIAAABLMMCEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAH5JREFUeNpiFBASVNfmv3n1IwMSYALi929/dkw1AcrBRZk5ODm/fvkjJsFR1aYvLcd969pHIJcJInn7xicg6eQhOXetjY6BIAtEVFWDD0g+vPdleu+NKxfeg0R5+Vg9AmSA/I0rH/379x8owigkImRqJXLt0ofPn37DbQMIMAA2Li0My8uNagAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
    background-position: 3px 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/vertical-decrement-arrow.png);
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAIAAABLMMCEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAHFJREFUeNpiFBASZAADPSOhS+feQdhMEEpEjKN5gpGRuTCKaEqeGicXc2q+OhMTI1RUx0DQyUMSyFBW4/UOkgEyWICSCVkqS2bfvX/ns7wST3C0woFdLxiNLeQ+fvj95tUPiFHcPCxAaxnhbkAGAAEGAAxaGY5HzMiTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
    background-position: 3px 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/vertical-increment-arrow.png);
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAIAAABLMMCEAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAH9JREFUeNpiFBASZMAATJZ2Ytw8LHC+kDC7ogov888fzFMWWXJxs/Dwsto5i4clKK5Z/IDl86ffa5c+yK3QgqgtSjn1799/JiBr67ond299BjL27Xh+5cJ7kLlADJScN+XW929/50y6BdHBzMHJCaSePf527eKH+3c+Q0QBAgwAkHcvV72C85gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    background-position: 3px 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement:active 
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/horizontal-decrement-arrow-active.png); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment:active 
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/horizontal-increment-arrow-active.png); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:active 
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/vertical-decrement-arrow-active.png); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:active 
{
    #background-image: url(Scrolling/black/vertical-increment-arrow-active.png); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track { -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); border-radius: 10px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{background-color: #151716;}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical
{
    height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #4d4d4d), color-stop(100%, #333333));
    border: 1px solid #0d0d0d;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal
{
    width: 50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4d4d4d), color-stop(100%, #333333));
    border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background-color: #3D3D3D;}


    </style>

 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: auto">
  <form style="width:100%;height:100%" runat="server" ID="ReportViewerForm">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="AjaxScriptManager" AsyncPostBackTimeout="0" runat="server" />
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%"><tr height="100%"><td width="100%">
   <RS:ReportViewerHost ID="ReportViewerControl" PageCountMode="Actual" runat="server" />
    </td></tr></table>
  </form>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

// =============================== COR-Code =================================

// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function () {
    var method;
    var noop = function () { };
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];

    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());


// ============================== End-COR-Code ==============================



Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.prototype._destroyTree = function(element) 
{
    var allnodes = element.getElementsByTagName('*'), length = allnodes.length;
    var nodes = new Array(length);
    for (var k = 0; k < length; k++) 
    {
        nodes[k] = allnodes[k];
    } // Next k 

    for (var j = 0, l = nodes.length; j < l; j++) 
    {
        var node = nodes[j];
        if (node.nodeType === 1) 
        {
            if (node.dispose && typeof (node.dispose) === "function") 
            {
                node.dispose();
            }
            else if (node.control && typeof (node.control.dispose) === "function") 
            {
                node.control.dispose();
            }
            var behaviors = node._behaviors;
            if (behaviors) 
            {
                behaviors = Array.apply(null, behaviors);
                for (var k = behaviors.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
                {
                    behaviors[k].dispose();
                }
            } // End if (behaviors) 

        } // End if (node.nodeType === 1) 

    } // Next j 
};


// ============================== COR-Code ==============================

Array.prototype.contains = function (obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}; // End Function contains


// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars(urlHref) 
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = urlHref.slice(urlHref.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) 
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    } // Next i

    return vars;
} // End Function getUrlVars




function initLanguage()
{
    var language = null;
    var StyleSheetSet = null;
    var BrowserLanguage = <%= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null ? "\"" + System.Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0]) + "\"" : "null" %>;

    if(BrowserLanguage == null)
        BrowserLanguage = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

    if(BrowserLanguage != null)
        BrowserLanguage = BrowserLanguage.substr(0,2).toLowerCase();



    var dictParameters = getUrlVars(this.location.href);

    if (dictParameters != null && dictParameters.contains("rc:Stylesheet"))
        StyleSheetSet = true;

    if (dictParameters != null && dictParameters.contains("in_sprache"))
        language = dictParameters["in_sprache"];

    if(language == null)
        language = BrowserLanguage;

    if(language == null)
        language = "de";

    language = language.toLowerCase();

    return language;
} // End function initLanguage


function TranslateParameterPrompts(iLanguageIndex)
{
    var eles = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var strParamTableId = "ParametersGridReportViewerControl";
    var tblParameters = null;
    var ParamLabels = null;


    for(var j = 0; j < eles.length; ++j)
    {
        // console.log(eles[j]);

        if(eles[j] != null && eles[j].id != null)
        {
            if(eles[j].id.slice(0, strParamTableId.length) == strParamTableId) // if startswith str
            {
                // console.log(eles[j].id);
                tblParameters = eles[j];
                break;
            }
            // else console.log(eles[j].id);
        } // End if(eles[j] != null && eles[j].id != null)

    } // Next j


    if(tblParameters != null)
        ParamLabels = tblParameters.getElementsByTagName("span");

    // var ParamLabels = document.querySelectorAll("table[id^='ParametersGridReportViewerControl'] span");
    if(ParamLabels != null)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < ParamLabels.length; ++i)
        {
            var strText = ParamLabels[i].innerHTML;

            if (strText != null && strText.indexOf('/') != -1 && strText.indexOf('<input') == -1 ) 
            {
                strText = strText.split('/');
                if (iLanguageIndex < strText.length)
                    strText = strText[iLanguageIndex];
                else 
                { 
                    if(strText.length > 0)
                        strText = strText[0];
                }

                ParamLabels[i].innerHTML = strText;
            } // End if (strText != null && strText.indexOf('/') != -1) 

        } // Next i

    } // End if(ParamLabels != null)

}


function fixReportingServices(container)
{
    var language = initLanguage();

    switch (language)
    {
        case "fr":
            iLanguageIndex = 1;
            break;
        case "it":
            iLanguageIndex = 2;
            break;
        case "en":
            iLanguageIndex = 3;
            break;
        default: // "DE" 
            iLanguageIndex = 0;
    } // End Switch

    TranslateParameterPrompts(iLanguageIndex);
}


// needed when AsyncEnabled=true. 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () { fixReportingServices('rpt-container'); });

  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

(**Note:** this is for SSRS 2016 - not necessarely backward or forward compatible, but you get the idea)